# Determine the number of solutions for $x^2 = c$ such that $c \in \mathbb{F}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-systems

I am working on the problem from number system class taught by the professor who shares his knowledge about the relation of abstract algebra and number systems.  Here is the problem:

Assume $c$ and $\mathbb{F}$ are arbitrary.  For $c \in \mathbb{F}$, how many distinct solutions can the equation $x^2 = c$ have?  Be specific about what properties of $c$ lead to what number of solution and justify your reasoning using properties a field must have.

**Thoughts for the Problem**

I believe that there is a solution when $c = 0$ for any field.  If $c = 1$, and we have $\mathbb{F}_2$, then we obtain exactly one solution.  BUT if $\mathbb{F}$ is any arbitrary field and $c = 1$, then we have two solutions.  This situation could occur the same way for any arbitrary field and $c \geq 2$, being an integer.  The thing is: what if $c$ is either trascendental or irrational (like roots number)?  Is it possible for the equation to have solutions like this?  I am having a hard time, approaching this problem.

Comment: In the field with three elements, $0,1,2,$ there are no square roots of $2.$

Comment: Since you are working with a field, a lot of your intuition from working with real numbers and complex numbers follows through.  In any case, you have $x$ is a root if and only if $-x$ is a root.  So unless $x = -x$, and that only works for fields with characteristic two, or if $x = 0$, you know that you either have two roots or none.  Oh, and you know you only have two roots, because if $\alpha$ is a root then $x^2 - c = (x+\alpha)(x-\alpha)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equivalently, we are talking about the solutions over $x \in \mathbb{F}$ to $x^2 - c= 0$, where $c\in \mathbb{F}$.

In any case, one of two things happens: either there is no solution, or there is a solution $d$ such that $d^2 = c$.  In such a case, we may write
$$
x^2 - c = (x+d)(x-d)
$$ 
So that $x^2 = 0$ if and only if $x = d$ or $x = -d$.  If (and only if) $d = -d$, our solution is unique.  Otherwise, there are two solutions.

Note that 
$d = -d \iff 2d = 0$.  So, if $c$ has a unique square root, then either $c = 0$ or there is an element $d \in \mathbb{F}$ for which $2d = 0$.

I'm not sure what you mean with the statement "what if $c$ is transcendental or irrational". What about it?

Comment: I mean "what is $c$ is trascendental, such as $e$"?  I'm just thinking a bit more about this problem.

Comment: I'm actually thinking about $c$ being any real number.  I wonder what happens if $c$ is ANY real number instead of perfect squares.

Comment: Well, in such a case, we are considering the field $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$ (remember, $c$ has to be a member of our field). In this case, $c$ will only have a square root if it's non-negative.  If it is negative, it will have no square roots, if it is $0$, it will have $1$, and if it is positive it will have $2$.